# Is libstdc++ coming from system or gcc or gcc-c++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Is libstdc++ coming from system or gcc or gcc-c++?

If it comes from gcc or system, can we build C++ program with gcc only (link to libstdc++)?

In short, my question is that if I can build c++ program without gcc-c++ installed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I can't figure out if you have a very basic question or if you're trying to be really smart about linking to libstdc++... the way it is, the question is unclear.

Comment: Short version - if your gcc built without C++ support - no, you can't. Just use your package manager to determine which package specific file belongs to - this will give you an answer for your distribution.

Comment: In short, my question is that if I can build c++ program without gcc-c++ installed?

Comment: You sort of need a C++ compiler if you want to compile C++ code.

Comment: You can compile without `gcc` using `clang` or any other C++ compiler.

Comment: There is no such a thing as `gcc-c++`. If you, by some reasons, have it - it was introduced by your distribution maintainers and without specifying what you use it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

- The standard library comes with the compiler.
- You can link statically, yes.
- You can't build a c++ program without a c++ compiler. You can *run* a c++ program without a c++ compiler, however.

Comment: why I can't build c++ with gcc compiler? I notice some articles use can use gcc to compile c++ and link gcc with libstdc++.

Comment: in brief, my question is if my linux just install gcc withoug gcc-c++,  can i build c++ cpp only use gcc not with gcc-c++

Comment: Noone said that you can't. gcc stands for Gnu Compiler Collection (was Gnu C Compiler - long time ago). It may (optionally, configured at compiler's build time) support C++, D, java, objective-C, maybe something else. So if _your_ gcc comes with disabled C++ support - you can't use it to build C++ programs, although it's very very rare.

Comment: @jiafu are you aware that you should use the `g++` command to link c++ code? `g++` is GCC, but it's set up for c++. It's good form to simply use `g++` at all times when working with c++.